# Forming a request.post from a curl on python

Tags: python, api

I have a small project i need a tempmail for, so i found this site *https://mail.tm/en*, so i was trying to acess the post via the api and instructions given here *https://api.mail.tm/*.

As I am new at working with curl and so on I have a lot of problems authorizing into an account there.

First of all i got an CURL link on site like this one:

`curl -X POST "https://api.mail.tm/accounts" -H  "accept: application/ld+json" -H  "Authorization: testing" -H  "Content-Type: application/ld+json" -d "{\"address\":\"test\",\"password\":\"stackoverflow\"}"`

I tried to form it all in a post request, so i did this

```
headers = {"accept": "application/ld+json", "Authorization": "header", "Content-Type": "application/ld+json"}
data = "{\"address\":\"zashyganii\",\"password\":\"chertila\"}"
mail = requests.post("https://api.mail.tm/accounts", data = data, headers = headers)
print(mail.status_code)
```

the error code is 400, noted on the api site like this.

```
400 Error:
Response body
Download
{
  "@context": "/contexts/ConstraintViolationList",
  "@type": "ConstraintViolationList",
  "hydra:title": "An error occurred",
  "hydra:description": "address: This value is not a valid email address.\naddress: The domain \"\" is not valid.",
  "violations": [
    {
      "propertyPath": "address",
      "message": "This value is not a valid email address."
    },
    {
      "propertyPath": "address",
      "message": "The domain \"\" is not valid."
    }
  ]
}
```

Could you please turn this curl in to a `request.post` on python so it will work for this api

Comment: Have you tried with a valid emal?

Comment: Did you read the error message? Your “address” isn’t a valid email address.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there are not any problem with the request. It's a validation fail.